# Cofibrations in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, finite-groups

I am studying cofibrations from Dr. Weibel's The K book. There the definition of cofibrations for a pointed category **C** is

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWd6I.png)

Now given any abelian category if I take the monomorphisms they provides me with the subcategory of cofibrations. My question is suppose I take category of abelian groups then apart from the injective homomorphisms can I take any other class of morphisms which are cofibrations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you always have the two extremes: the class of isomorphisms, and the class of all morphisms.